# How to use the AWUS036H on MacBook Pro with Lion and Backtrack in VM?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, virtualbox, osx-lion, backtrack

I have the AWUS036H USB WiFi adapter and have recently upgraded the OSX to Lion. The thing is, there are no drivers for Lion for the AWUS036H, and I would have to boot into 32bit mode every time I want to launch the adapter as per instructions here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9_HAGi1ce0

I also want to install BackTrack as I deal in networks a lot for my company. While this would be a simple matter on any other laptop, the company issued Macbook does not allow booting into any OS other than MacOSX or Windows with Bootcamp.

Now, since dual booting into BT is not an option, I would like Backtrack to run in VM inside my MacOSX Lion - and this it does. It works like a charm inside VirtualBox. But since there are no 64bit drivers for the wifi adapter, Lion doesn't recognize it and cannot install it. This, in turn, means that Backtrack cannot see it even though AWUS036H usually works flawlessly with BT.

How can I make my VM-based BT see the wifi adapter even if the parent OS doesn't see it, if at all? Is there a way, or am I better off buying a new WiFi adapter that supports OSX 10.7 such as the AWUS036NHR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass through the USB device directly to the virtual machine.  Here's a good walkthrough with screenshots (albeit using a different host OS, an older version of VirtualBox, and for a different device): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=570452

Comment: That was it, thanks! All I needed was to create a USB filter and the device goes right to VB, brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just go to USB devices in the VM menu and the adapter will be there and works well.

I'm running Mountain Lion 64-bit on my MacBook Air. It does seem to be a no-go at getting it to work in OS X as a WiFi adaptor, unless you switch to 32-bit, not willing. Now I see most of your problem was already addressed and I know that the above was redundant, however I do have something to add.

You can dual boot a Mac. You have to use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/). This will let you repartition your drive and install any Linux distribution you want. I could not get it to work with FileVault turned on, so I didn't keep it due to that and the hard drive space limitations of the MacBook Air models.